# AVAudioPlayer sound too low at starting, after some sound get louder

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

In my situation, when I pressed play button sound comes low at starting and after some time it comes louder for speaker. In my project too many audio files are available. When I pressed first then it starts with low sound and when I pressed second and third it starts and all played in loud sound from speaker. Every time when I pressed play button, it executed below code.

```
- (SWYAudioBoardPlayer*) initWithMediaKey:(NSString *) mediaKey{
self.session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; // Object declare above 
NSError *error = nil;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"audioUrl" error:&error];
[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
isPause = false;
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
defaultAVAudioSessionCategory = [self.session category]; // Object declare above 
[self loudSpeakerOn:true];
return [self init]; }

- (void) loudSpeakerOn:(BOOL)isLoudSpeaker{
[self.session setActive:NO error:nil];
BOOL success;
NSError* error;
success = [self.session overrideOutputAudioPort:isLoudSpeaker?AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);
[self.session setActive:YES error:nil];}
```